# ubuntu along side windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I downloaded from the official website. I burned correctly the dvd with ubuntu, i restart my computer and just like the installation instructions says i saw the welcoming screen, my problem is:

Installation type it only gives me 2 options: "replace windows 7", or "something else". It says nothing about "install ubuntu along side windows 7" like one of the images in the instructions says.

I don't understand what is happening,

one more thing, from the dvd i burned i'm trying ubuntu but how do i exit?? eject the dvd and then go back to windows.

thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

To install alongside windows follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) instruction

To get back to windows just shutdown your ubuntu session,
remove dvd and again boot to windows,...

Answer (score 0):

U can always use something else to dual boot OS's.

But first u r gonna nee to create 2 extra partitions.
One for ubuntu > 8GB nd the other swap => RAM size... Id suggest using windows defualt partition creator to do so. then  during ubuntu install process, select the ubuntu partion u just created nd format it as ext4 nd select mount as "/" then format the other partition which is => RAM as swap...
Then proceed as the install says.

*edit: backup ur data before partitionig to be safe. nd make sure u have Windows install media so that u can recover incase goes wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest you improve the spelling.